# Is there any quick way to change .net framework projects to .net core projects?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a solution with 58 projects. 1 mvc projects and others are .net libraries (.net frameowrk 4.6.2 dlls). 2 projects have nuget packages...

**Is there any quick way to change .net framework to .net core ?**

I mean do I have to create new project and create 57 projects ( +1 mvc core) and add cs files in them ?

***Note***: I know, I need to look at some nuget packages to support .net core and I have a lot of work for mvc core too.

Comment: No, see it as a port.

Comment: @Faisal did you read or try that article? It talks about project.json...

Comment: For your class libraries, you can attempt to target .NET Standard. If you can retarget them to a version of .NET Standard, you can then use them in any Core project. As far as migrating from MVC to Core goes, though, that's an entirely manually affair.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for your comment. Maybe I understood it wrongly. Let me clear; so if I re-target all projects ( not mvc ) to .net standart, can I use them with .net framework and .net core projects ? Sorry for mixing things. I'm confused a little bit.

Comment: Basically, yes. .NET Standard is basically just an API footprint. There's different versions of .NET Standard, with each version progressively supporting more APIs. All the other .NET family of libraries, Core, Full Framework, Xamarin, etc. implement some version of .NET Standard, so you basically target the lowest version that includes the API footprint you need. Any version of .NET Standard works with Core 1.X. Core 2.X requires .NET Standard 2.0+. .NET Framework 4.6.2 requires at least .NET Standard 1.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no quick way to migrate from .NET Framework to .NET Core, I migrate medium solution with 4 projects and it is was not fun, all work should be done manually.

If we check the [docs about porting to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) there is nothing quick and easy. Even just 1st item in the list could be real pain, especially in big projects.

> 1. Identify and account for your third-party dependencies.
>
>    This will involve understanding what your third-party dependencies
>      are, how you depend on them, how to see if they also run on .NET Core,
>      and steps you can take if they don't.

There only little help comes from  [API Portability Analyzer tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-apiport/), but it is just show you report how you codebase is portable, but port process still should be done manually.

For my migration I used advised approach from [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4874) and looked at reports from API Portability Analyzer tool:

> 1. `dotnet new` a core template
> 2. Add stuff to it until it builds your project
> 3. delete the old csproj file